# Como agregar un icon en campos

Tags: html, css

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me podrian decir como hago para agregar un icon en donde marque con azul, agrego la imagen para mayor compresion

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="index.php?action=clientaccess">
                   <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-23" data-validate = "Nombre is reauired">
                        <span class="label-input100" class="focus-input100">Correo Electronico</span>
                        <input required class="input100" type="email" name="email" id="inputEmail1" placeholder="Correo Electronico">
                        <span class="focus-input100" data-symbol="&#xf206;"></span> 
                  </div>
                  <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-23" data-validate = "Nombre is reauired">
                        <span class="label-input100">Contraseña</span>
                        <input required class="input100" type="password" name="password" id="inputEmail1" placeholder="Contraseña" required>
                        <span class="focus-input100" data-symbol="&#xf190;"></span> 
                  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

utiliza el CDN de bootstrap ICON

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">`
```

buscas el icono que más te agrade y lo colocas donde estimes convieniente

(email)

```
<i class="bi bi-envelope-fill"></i>
```

(llave)

```
<i class="bi bi-key-fill"></i>
```

Comment: Podemos usar font awesome también, no te digo que lo uses obligatoriamente, solo es un comentario, además ese "donde creas conveniente" no solucina nada, el usuario preguntó "cómo agregar iconos en un input" mas tu has respondido "cómo agregar Bootstrap icons"

Comment: Tienes razón, lo tomaré en cuenta